# How to best create Uno card and deck with nested enum

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to create a simple version of the Uno card game beginning with creating an Array of Card() objects to comprise the Deck() which includes instance methods such as initializeDeck() and shuffleDeck().

I'm new to enumerations and can't seem to find information for using them efficiently to the effect of creating and assigning a Card() object with a color and faceValue based on two of every possible combination (minus one of every pair of zeros). It might not even be the most efficient or effective way but my idea was the following:

```
struct Card {
        
        enum color: String {
            case red = ""
            case blue = ""
            case yellow = ""
            case green = ""
        }
        
        enum faceValue: Int {
            case zero = 0
            case one = 1
            case two = 2
            case three = 3
            case four = 4
            case five = 5
            case six = 6
            case seven = 7
            case eight = 8
            case nine = 9
        }
        
    }
```

Following this Struct declaration I'd create a loop such as

```
// Main

var Deck: [Cards] = []

for _ in 0...96 {

    Deck.append(Card(color: "iterate through four colors for every one faceVal twice (except for zero; only once)", faceVal "iterate through 0...9 (for every color)"))

}
```

Although, I'm not quite sure that's how you initialize the nested enums (within the Card struct) for the color & faceVal. In addition to that I'm not sure how you'd manage indexing(?) through them to assign each color to each faceVal.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm also newly familiar with CustomStringConvertible and wondering if this might be worked in some way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Swift 4.2 you can use `CaseIterable` to get an array of all enum cases.

Simply change your enums to conform to the protocol:

```
enum color: String, CaseIterable {
    // ...
}

enum faceValue: String, CaseIterable {
    // ...
}
```

And perform a double for loop:

```
for color in color.allCases {
    for faceValue in faceValue.allCases {
        Deck.append(Card(color: color, faceVal: faceValue))
    }
}
```

Also; structs, enums and classes should have a name that starts with a capital letter, so that would be `Color`, `FaceValue` and `Card`; whereas properties and variables should start with a lowercase letter, so that would be `deck`. That way you can see if a name is a class name or a variable name easily.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've corrected the casing and defined the double for in loop that you explained, presumably within the Card struct as you wouldn't be able to access 'color' in 'color.allCases' otherwise (?) - however, I'm getting a 'Expect declaration error' with a reference to '1. In declaration of 'Card''.

Edit: I tried to upvote your post, although I don't have enough reputation to do so, apparently.

Comment: You still need to define properties in your Card struct, simply defining the enums in there is not enough. You should add `let faceValue: FaceValue` and `let color: Color` in your Card struct, then this code should work. I assumed you omitted it in your question for simplicity.

Comment: Little did you know I'm just a painful newbie to Swift & XCode, lol - I appreciate your help!  I wasn't sure if the enumeration 'Color' for example was assigned a Case, say "green".

Comment: lol, no problem, that's why we're here. You can find more info about enums, declarations and everything else swift in the [Swift Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) (links to the enumerations page)